# PHP solution to alternate results from a query by a variable (1,2,3,4 - 1,2,3,4)

Tags: php

I have tried a MySQL solution but it does not seem practical and I get a query that takes to long.

I am looking for a PHP solution to this problem:

I have inside my table rows with product data coming from 4 different sites.

I query them using some conditions and I get a result variable:

```
$result = mysql_query("my query");
```

Now, I retrieve the data like this:

```
while($slice = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $product_data = $slice['productdata'];
   $site     = $slice['site']; 
}
```

The problem is that I want to display product data by alternating the $site variable:

```
1. product from site 1;

2. product from site 2;

3. product from site 3;

4. product from site 4;
```

If all the products from site 2 have been listed, then list the other remaining products like this:

```
1. product from site 1;

2. priduct from site 3;

3. product from site 4;
```

And so on.

IMPORTANT: I am paginating the results so the solution cannot break pagination. So i need a total rows number I can paginate.

Could there be a PHP solution?

**UPDATE:**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT site, product FROM ".$table." WHERE my mysql conditions LIMIT ".$offset.", ".$rowsperpage."");

$rowsperpage = 20;
```

**If site 3 has much more rows then the others, using the code would generate:**

Page 1:

- Product from site 1;
- Product from site 2;
- Product from site 3;
- Product from site 1;
- Product from site 2;
- Product from site 3;
- Product from site 3;
- Product from site 3;
- .....
- until 20

Page 2:

- Product from site 1;
- Product from site 2;
- Product from site 3;
- Product from site 1;
- Product from site 2;
- Product from site 3;
- Product from site 3;
- Product from site 3;
- .....
- until 20

Page 3 would display the remaining site 3 rows:

- Product from site 3;
- Product from site 3;
- Product from site 3;
- .....
- until 20

The problem is Page 1 and Page 2 will display more site 3 products than the others.

This is because of the mysql query which has rows mixed and ordered by random. And when I call 20 of them, the sites won't have equal number of rows.

**I want to achieve something like:**

Page 1:

- Product from site 1;
- Product from site 2;
- Product from site 3;
- Product from site 1;
- Product from site 2;
- Product from site 3;
- Product from site 1;
- Product from site 2;
- Product from site 3;
- .....
- until 20

Page 2:

- Product from site 1;
- Product from site 2;
- Product from site 3;
- Product from site 3;
- Product from site 2;
- **Product from site 3;**
- **Product from site 3;**
- **Product from site 3;**

..... 
until 20

**What I want to achieve works with the code only if I have the query on each paginated page without the offset and limit**

Comment: Can you store all the results in an array, and display/paginate on the array instead?

Comment: I can use array_slice() to paginate an array. I think there could be a way to use 4 queries, each one for each site and add the results inside an array; but not sure

Comment: Note: Please avoid using `mysql_query()` and the other `mysql_xx()` functions: they are being deprecated and are not recommended for use. You should switch either to the newer `mysqli_xx()` functions, or the PDO library. Please see the PHP manual for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's (attempt #2) at a solution that may work for you.

After more thought and comments, it appears that using MySQL to handle pagination via `LIMIT`/`OFFSET` will not be an easy task to accomplish considering the ordering you need. That said, the pagination should be handled soley in PHP - the caveat here being that you have to load all of the MySQL results during every page load.

The idea is to build a 2D-array with each "site" as the index and each sub-array as the list of "products" for each site. After this is built, find the length of the longest list of products - that number will let us know how high we need to iterate to using this "buckets" method.

Now, iterate from `0` to `the length of the longest list of products` and, in a nested loop, iterate through each site. If the site doesn't have a product for the current index, skip it; otherwise:

- If the current `$offest` is greater than 0, skip the current product and decrememnt `$offset` by 1.
- If `$offset` is less than or equal to 0, output the product!

Sample Code:

```
// define what page we're on (will probably come from $_GET)
$page = 1;

// define how many products to display per-page
$productsPerPage = 20;

// calculate the current offset based on the page-# and the #-per-page
$offset = (($page - 1) * $productsPerPage);

// get the full results from the database
$results = mysql_query("your query");
if (mysql_num_rows($results) <= $offset) {
    // the current page is too high; you could set it to the last page,
    // or loop back to page #1, display an error, etc.
    return;
}

$sites = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (!isset($sites[$row['site']])) {
        // initialize the products-array for this site
        $sites[$row['site']] = array();
    }
    // add this product to the array for this site
    $sites[$row['site']][] = $row['productdata'];
}

// get the largest-number of products for a given site
$maxProducts = 0;
foreach ($sites as $products) {
    if ($maxProducts == 0) {
        // set the first list of products as the "most"
        $maxProducts = count($products);
    } else if (($count = count($products)) > $maxProducts) {
        // the current list of products is larger than what we've found
        $maxProducts = $count;
    }
}

// iterate from the $siteOffset to the highest-number of products
for ($i = 0; $i < $maxProducts; $i++) {
    // iterate through each site and check if it has a product at this "level"
    foreach ($sites as $site => $products) {
        if (isset($products[$i])) {
            // there is a product for this site on this "level";
            // if we haven't reached our offset yet, skip it
            if ($offset-- > 0) continue;
            // otherwise, output it!
            echo $products[$i] . ' from site ' . $site . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ty for answering. Lets say the query displays 20 products per page. From the 20 products: 5 are from site 1, 5 from site 2 and 10 from site 3. I did a var_dump for $slices. The code will llist more products from site 3 since from the 20 selected, 10 are from site 3

Comment: Let me try and explain. I query about 500 rows from which lets say 50 are from site 1, 100 from site 2 and 350 from site 3, all mixed. If I query all of them and I use your code on that page, it works perfectly. The problem is when I use pagination. Lets say I paginate using 20 rows per page. On page 1, if I query the first 20 rows, I'll get lets say 2 rows from site 1, 8 from site two and 10 from site3. On the second page, from the 20 rows I'll get maybe 5 from site 1, 5 from site 2 and 10 from site 3. Your code will work if I query all the posts on every paginated page and use array_slice

Comment: I have updated my answer and I am really not sure how to explain, I am a newb and not an english native.

Comment: Ty very much, you have been great to help, hope you understood a little what I ment.

Comment: @webmasters Code and explanation has been updated; hopefully this should suit your needs =]

Comment: I have tested it, ty! If I have 180 products and I set the offset to 160 the code shows the last 20 products which is perfect. But if I set the offset to 140, it shows the last 40 products instead of showing 20 (rows from 140 to 160)

Comment: @webmasters Did you work things out, or would you like to go to chat still?