# Php or MYSQL solution on how to display MYSQL data by alternating rows depending on a criteria

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for a solution to this problem for quite some time, asked a related question but no luck. I'll try to ask very straight to the point maybe someone can shed some light.

*If this question gets a valid answer I'll delete the similar one.
I believe this question is clearer.*

In a database table I store data about "used cars".

Lets say I have **5 BMW** used cars (I'd wish:), **4 Mercedes** and **20 Vauxhalls**.

They are ordered by rand inside the table.

I query the data and I apply pagination to it, showing **6 cars per page** (5 pages total).

How can I display the data like this:

Page 1:

- First BMW, First Mercedes, First Vauxhall,
- Second BMW, Second Mercedes, Second Vauxhall

Page 2:

- Third BMW, Third Mercedes, Third Vauxhall,
- Fourth BMW, Fourth Mercedes, Fourth Vauxhall

Page 3:

- Fifth BMW, Fifth Vauxhall, Sixth Vauxhall,
- Seventh Vauxhall, Eight Vauxhall, Night Vauxhall

Page 4, and 5:

- will display all the remaining Vauxhalls.

  1. Some guys said this can be done by using a very complicated mysql query which takes forever to execute. Look at this stack question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959414/mysql-how-do-i-order-results-by-alternating-1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3-rows-i).
  2. User newfurniturey gave a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971118/php-solution-to-alternate-results-from-a-query-by-a-variable-1-2-3-4-1-2-3-4) for a similar problem but it did not work. I think my question was not clear. I thank him very much.

Comment: How about having a separate table for each car type? Then you could easily know how many cars of each type you have, and make an algorithm from there.

Comment: I think the criteria for how you want the output is not very clear. Are you trying to get results that have as few repeat car makes as possible? In other words, you want to show variety first, and have same-makes that are left over at the bottom of the sort. Correct?

Comment: An interesting problem, and I can't think of a solution that would scale well. In your actual application how many rows would you foresee being returned? Not per page, but in total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have a category (Make) and a vehicle (Vehicle ID), and you want every page to show one Vehicle from every Make, unless there are no more vehicles left on that make?

Assuming you have a table `Vehicles` with the fields `make` and `vin`:

first find the makes:

```
$q = "SELECT make FROM Vehicles"
$r=mysqli_query($dbconnect, $q);
$make= mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
array_unshift($make, "nomake"); //add so the first make is not a position zero
```

Then, build an array that matches the vin to the make:

```
$q = "SELECT make, vin FROM Vehicles ORDER BY make"
$r=mysqli_query($dbconnect, $q);
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
  $vehicle[$record['vin']]=$record['make'];
}
```

Then, build your array in the order for your page:

```
$onpage=0;
$numperpage = 5; //number of vehicles per page
foreach($vehicle as $vkey => $vvalue){
  if (array_search($vvalue,$lastvalue)){
    $finalorder[$vkey] = $vvalue;
    $lastvalue[$onpage]= $vvalue;
    $onpage=$onpage<$numperpage?$onpage++:0;
  }
  if($onpage==0){
    unset($lastvalue);
  }
}
var_dump($finalorder);
```

This may need a little cleaning up, but it should work.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I was thinking, but it doesn't scale well. If there are a large number of records, we have to get them all at once, which kind of defeats the point of pagination. But I'm not really seeing any other way.

Comment: I just noticed that I don't have an `else` after the if.  That would be required as well, or you would just ignore the vehicles that aren't in order.  I think you need another array to add them to, and then array_push them to the end.  It is a little like a bubble sort.

Comment: There is a lot of sorting and organizing going on with many records.  It can't be helped; you are asking the computer to do a lot of work.

Comment: Yes, I am working on a could that would do it myself, but I need to use load the query on each page which indeed defeats the scope of pagination. Lucky my table has only about 1000 rows and I don't think there could be a performance issue

Comment: I will post in about half an hour my solution also, maybe you guys can correct it